# Set-Cookie header not accepted because of invalid domain attribute

Tags: cookies, web-development-server, setcookie

I can't seem to set cookies on my frontend application, after authorizing with the googleOAuth. I am using expressjs with the cookieparser on the backend and react for the frontend app. 
**Express code snippet:**

```
res.cookie("email", user.email, {
        maxAge: 3600000,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
        secure: true,
        domain: 'process.env.FRONTEND_URL'
      });

res.redirect(process.env.FRONTEND_URL)
```

When it comes to domain cookie option I've tried every combination of the url parts
I've hosted it on render so urls go like this: [frontend.onrender.com, backend.onrender.com]

But when I get redirected here is what the warning for the cookies says 
**This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url.**

**Domain attributes I've tried** 
https://frontend.onrender.com 
frontend.onrender.com 
.onrender.com 
onrender.com 
.com

I've already check my env variables, and they are correctly set

Just nothing works